# Laravel - Never ending queue worker that would process all records

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I would like to run a queue worker that would never end and would process all the records in a table constantly (i.e. check their status via an API). Currently the options I thought of were:

- Schedule a job every x minutes that would add a job to queue for every record in a table (problem here is that it is undefined how long that will take so a lot of time could be wasted without jobs or the jobs will stack up and plug up the queue).
- Add a job to queue that would loop through all the records and then at the end add itself to the queue again.

The second option seems the best so far, however, it seems a bit *hacky* and the queue worker would have to have a huge timeout to make sure it processes all records and adds itself to the queue again.

I was wondering if there is a better pattern/technique/tool to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like you should be using the task scheduler, not a queue.

Comment: But I'd like a worker that would loop through all records indefinitely?

Comment: Why would that be a queue worker and not a scheduled task or a daemon?

Comment: You could just have the job put a version of itself back on the queue once it had finished...

Comment: @aarcarr That's my current best shot, however, it seems a bit hacky. It would be very prone to failing though if there are some issues before the end of the script and it does not add itself back to the queue.

Comment: A never ending job would fail at the same point though ?

Comment: @aarcarr that's a good point, that's why I would put it under some supervisor so that the process is always booted up back again. Whereas with simple jobs queue, if it fails then it will not be back up until manually added again?

Comment: What is it you're doing ?

Comment: @aarcarr as per question, I need to continuously process records, check their status against external API etc.